# Generate dummy absence data from datetime

Tags: r, date, random

I have 'presence' data that i would like to use in a binomial analysis of presence/absence that looks like this:

```
          datetime    id location longitude latitude presence_absence
1 25/04/2022 21:13 63871        A  106.8051  19.2334                1
2 26/04/2022 21:10 63871        B  104.3524  18.1435                1
3  10/12/2022 6:29 63871        A  106.8051  19.2334                1
4  8/06/2023 19:20 63871        A  106.8051  19.2334                1
5  11/04/2022 8:05 63323        C  103.4527  20.1236                1
```

Therefore I need to generate dummy 'absence' data for each location.

I would like to generate random 'absence' observations at a rate equal to the number of 'presence' observations for that location in that year.

E.g. if location A has 3 'presence' observations in year 2022 and 1 in 2023, I would like to generate 3 'absence' observations for 2022 and 1 for 2023.

However, these should not fall on any days with 'presence' observations at that location.

The outcome would look something like this:

```
           datetime    id location longitude latitude presence_absence
1  25/04/2022 21:13 63871        A  106.8051  19.2334                1
2  26/04/2022 21:10 63871        B  104.3524  18.1435                1
3   10/12/2022 6:29 63871        A  106.8051  19.2334                1
4   8/06/2023 19:20 63871        A  106.8051  19.2334                1
5   11/04/2022 8:05 63323        C  103.4527  20.1236                1
6   10/04/2022 4:44    NA        A  106.8051  19.2334                0
7   27/03/2022 7:44    NA        B  104.3524  18.1435                0
8   5/02/2022 14:31    NA        A  106.8051  19.2334                0
9   12/08/2023 6:52    NA        A  106.8051  19.2334                0
10   6/09/2022 2:42    NA        C  103.4527  20.1236                0
```

I am unsure how to achieve this and could not find any threads that address similar problems. Any help greatly appreciated!

### data

```
structure(list(datetime = c("25/04/2022 21:13", "26/04/2022 21:10", 
"10/12/2022 6:29", "8/06/2023 19:20", "11/04/2022 8:05"), id = c(63871L, 
63871L, 63871L, 63871L, 63323L), location = c("A", "B", "A", 
"A", "C"), longitude = c(106.805083, 104.35241, 106.805083, 106.805083, 
103.45271), latitude = c(19.2334, 18.1435, 19.2334, 19.2334, 
20.1236), presence_absence = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: The first thing to do is convert those character value to to real R datetimes. There are many asked and answered questions to do this on SO.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a function that generates a random timestamp in that particular year. There is very low probability that the randomly generated timestamp will be same as the presence data timestamp. However, this probability is non-zero so I have added a `while` loop to  replace the values if such overlap occurs.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

generate_random_timestamp <- function(dt) {
  yr <- year(dt)
  # 86400 are number of seconds in day, so it generates a random time
  # 365 are number of days in a year so it generates a random date
  val <- as.POSIXct(sample(86400, length(yr)) * sample(365, length(yr)), tz = "UTC")
  # Replace the year component with the year of our data.
  year(val) <- yr
  # If there is an overlap with the presence data 
  # then replace it with newly generated data
  inds <- val == dt
  while(any(inds)) {
    val[inds] <- as.POSIXct(sample(86400, sum(inds)) * sample(365, sum(inds)), tz = "UTC")
    year(val) <- yr
    inds <- val == dt
  }
  val
}
```

This function is then called for each `location` and appended to original dataset.

```
df <- df %>% mutate(datetime = dmy_hm(datetime))
df %>%
  mutate(presence_absence = 0) %>%
  mutate(datetime = generate_random_timestamp(datetime), .by = location) %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  arrange(location)

#              datetime    id location longitude latitude presence_absence
#1  2022-06-08 14:13:36 63871        A  106.8051  19.2334                0
#2  2022-02-03 15:45:00 63871        A  106.8051  19.2334                0
#3  2023-09-03 21:02:15 63871        A  106.8051  19.2334                0
#4  2022-04-25 21:13:00 63871        A  106.8051  19.2334                1
#5  2022-12-10 06:29:00 63871        A  106.8051  19.2334                1
#6  2023-06-08 19:20:00 63871        A  106.8051  19.2334                1
#7  2022-02-07 08:14:25 63871        B  104.3524  18.1435                0
#8  2022-04-26 21:10:00 63871        B  104.3524  18.1435                1
#9  2022-04-14 15:43:24 63323        C  103.4527  20.1236                0
#10 2022-04-11 08:05:00 63323        C  103.4527  20.1236                1
```

Comment: This does not take into account leap years or leap seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we could write a vectorized `rand_dttm()` function that takes years as argument and throws random minutes (formatted `"POSIXlt"`) of those years. I use `tz='UTC'`, you can also use a different time zone. First, we use `strptime` to get proper date format.

```
> dat$datetime <- strptime(dat$datetime, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', tz='UTC')
> 
> rand_dttm <- \(y) {
+   lapply(y, \(x) {
+     if (length(x) == 0L || is.na(x)) {
+       NA_integer_
+     }
+     as.POSIXlt(paste(x, c('01-01', '12-31'), sep='-'), tz='UTC') |> 
+       as.list() |> 
+       c(by='min') |> 
+       do.call(what='seq.POSIXt') |> 
+       sample(size=1L)
+   }) |> do.call(what='c')
+ }
> 
> set.seed(384666)
> res <- dat |> 
+   rbind(
+     do.call('rbind',
+             lapply(unique(dat$location), \(x) {
+               within(dat[dat$location == x, ], {
+                 datetime <- rand_dttm(strftime(datetime, '%Y'))
+                 id <- NA
+                 presence_absence <- 0
+               })
+             }))
+   )
```

### Gives

```
> res
              datetime    id location longitude latitude presence_absence
1  2022-04-25 21:13:00 63871        A  106.8051  19.2334                1
2  2022-04-26 21:10:00 63871        B  104.3524  18.1435                1
3  2022-12-10 06:29:00 63871        A  106.8051  19.2334                1
4  2023-06-08 19:20:00 63871        A  106.8051  19.2334                1
5  2024-04-11 08:05:00 63323        C  103.4527  20.1236                1
11 2022-02-13 22:02:00    NA        A  106.8051  19.2334                0
31 2022-05-26 10:49:00    NA        A  106.8051  19.2334                0
41 2023-09-13 23:56:00    NA        A  106.8051  19.2334                0
21 2022-06-17 13:16:00    NA        B  104.3524  18.1435                0
51 2024-02-29 16:50:00    NA        C  103.4527  20.1236                0
```

---

*Data:*

I changed the year of location *C* to *2024* to have a leap year.

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(datetime = c("25/04/2022 21:13", "26/04/2022 21:10", 
"10/12/2022 6:29", "8/06/2023 19:20", "11/04/2024 8:05"), id = c(63871L, 
63871L, 63871L, 63871L, 63323L), location = c("A", "B", "A", 
"A", "C"), longitude = c(106.805083, 104.35241, 106.805083, 106.805083, 
103.45271), latitude = c(19.2334, 18.1435, 19.2334, 19.2334, 
20.1236), presence_absence = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```